# AIR - How to skin NativeWindow

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

On my air application I'd like to create chromless nativewindow but I don't find how to do that.
Indeed, I success with window but with this component type each window appear on Wndows taskbar, so I must found how to do the same (skin, maximise, reduce, move...) with another component.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't think that you can do it like that. Maybe you can add a skinnable component to the native window and skin that. Take a look at: http://www.ben-morris.com/howto-add-flex-mx-controls-to-a-nativewindow-for-adobe-air

Answer (score 0):

change the property systemChorme as none and transparent as true
in xml file of application.( projectname-app.xml)

Comment: Yes I know that, but I'd like to skin the native window with color border custom title bar... But when I try to create skin, nativewindow is not avaliable. So I don't know how to do that. thanks for helping.